# iptables PREROUTING and POSTROUTING doesn't seem to forward any packets (OpenWRT)

Tags: networking, iptables, openwrt

[image: Here's a picture of my network]

I am trying to mirror all packets sent or received by Device B and send them to Device A for logging. I have an OpenWRT acting as a wireless access point, and I have issued the following commands to the OpenWRT router via ssh:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -d 192.168.1.252 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.251
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -s 192.168.1.252 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.251
```

When I run iptables --list -t mangle I get the following:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# iptables --list -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fwmark     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
TEE        all  --  anywhere             192.168.1.252        TEE gw:192.168.1.251

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
mssfix     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
TEE        all  --  192.168.1.252        anywhere             TEE gw:192.168.1.251

Chain fwmark (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain mssfix (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN /* wan (mtu_fix) */ TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
```

I have opened Wireshark on Device A in promiscuous mode, BUT when I do things on Device B (like connecting to neverssl.com in my browser, or pinging google.com, I don't see the traffic on Device A. What am I doing wrong?

(Note1: If it makes any difference, I have also tried connecting Device A to the OpenWRT router wirelessly, to no avail.)

(Note2: There ARE other devices connected to the Netgear Router, but nothing else connected to the OpenWRT router.)

Comment: (Apologies if this is the wrong place for this- I was directed here or Unix/Linux by Networking Stack exchange)

Comment: try **-t nat** instead of mangle see if that helps.

Comment: Just tried -t nat instead of -t mangle (after a fresh reboot), and tried -t nat and -t mangle (as consecutive commands), still didn't work

Comment: I have cat'd /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward, and got 1, as expected

Comment: I'm trying to get a better understanding of pre-routing and post-routing; I think I might have to switch my -s and my -d? Because I want packets which appear to be from .252 BEFORE it goes to the router, and packets that are destined for .252 AFTER routing?