# Iptables rules seem to be missing packets?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, iptables, sniffing

On my home network (192.168.1.0/24), I am trying to use `iptables` to silently clone all wifi TCP/UDP traffic to/from my Xbox One to my Windows 10 desktop, for packet sniffing via Wireshark.

Due to locational constraints limiting ethernet connections, I'm attempting to do this via two wireless access points that share one network, with their LAN ports being the only Ethernet connection in the setup:

  `|<--[Ethernet To Cable Modem]
  |                             \  \  \
  |                              \  \  \
  |                               \  \  \
  |   _________________________    \  \  \
  └--| NETGEAR R6260           |   |  |  |
     | SSID: TheNewNetwork(5G) |   |  |  |
     | stock firmware, gateway |   |  |  |
  ┌--|_192.168.1.1_____________|   |  |  |
  |      ________________________  /  /  /
  |    ╙|_ PRINTER 192.168.1.14__|/  /  /
  |      ________________________/  /  /
  |    ╙|_ AMAZON 192.168.1.15__/| /  /
  |      ______________________/_ /  /
  |    ╙|_ AMAZON 192.168.1.16___|  /
  |      _____________________________
  |    ╙|_ DESKTOPWIN10 192.168.1.10__|
  |      __________________________
  |    ╙|_ Nexus-5X 192.168.1.13___|
  |      ___________________________
  |    ╙|_ GALAXY-S8 192.168.1.17___|
  |
  |
  |                            \  \  \
  |                             \  \  \
  |   _______________________    \  \  \
  └--| LINKSYS E2500         |   |  |  |
     | SSID: TheOtherNetwork |   |  |  |
     | Tomato w/ iptables    |   |  |  |
     |_192.168.1.2___________|   |  |  |
         ________________________/  /  /
       ╙|_ XBOXONE 192.168.1.12_/_|/  /
                               /  /  /`

The Linksys E2500 has been flashed with Tomato V1.28 (build 140) and is running the `iptables` framework. DHCP and NAT are off.  The Xbox connected to its unsecured wireless access point (SSID: *TheOtherNetwork*).

Everything else is on the WPA2-secured Netgear wireless (SSID: *TheNewNetwork*), per usual.  The Linksys IP (*192.168.1.2*) is static, and the Windows (*192.168.1.10*) and Xbox (*192.168.1.12*) IPs are assigned by DHCP reservation on the Netgear, which also assigns non-reserved DHCP addresses to everything else (printer, Amazon Fire TV Sticks [x2], smartphones), and handles the NAT for WAN-bound traffic.  This network arrangement seems to work flawlessly for all "normal" use cases.

Originally, I thought I could just throw in some [packet cloning](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=49564) `iptables` rules on the Linksys that match on the Xbox's IP, like:

`iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -s 192.168.1.12 -j ROUTE --gw 192.168.1.10 --tee
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -d 192.168.1.12 -j ROUTE --gw 192.168.1.10 --tee`

...but finding very few Xbox packets in my Wireshark feed, I decided to dig more into if the rules (that were meant to catch all Xbox traffic) were even getting triggered/matched (since that needs to happen before the `ROUTE` target even comes into play to get packets to Windows/Wireshark).

So, to get a full packet-triggering-debugging snapshot, I setup similarly-triggered rules for each IP address on the network, with a simple `-j ACCEPT` target, and with a "catch all" rule at the end of the chain that should trigger no matter what.  Then I fired up the Xbox and played a minute or so of an online first-person shooter (which worked fine as far as I could tell from the Xbox).

After a minute, this is what I got from the `iptables` rule list summary:

`root@E2500-Host:/# iptables -t mangle -vnL PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    68 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.12         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.12
  408 60499 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.10         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.1          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.1
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.13         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.13
    1   351 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.14         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.14
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.15         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.15
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.1.16         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.16
    1   344 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`

***WHAT?!?***  One measly packet from the Xbox?  I was playing an online first person shooter for a solid minute, with dozens of real-world opponent's positions updated from the server many times per second.  (I've read enough on this particular game to expect UDP for this exchange.)   There *MUST BE* more traffic than that between *192.168.1.12* and the outside world, and it *MUST BE* getting handled by the Linksys router that is running `iptables`, since the Xbox is only connected to the internet via the Linksys unsecured access point, *TheOtherNetwork*.

As a possibly-related side note: Other oddities include 0 triggered packets for any inbound traffic to any local IP (although maybe not unexpected for the non-Xbox devices on the other access point), and the fact that it caught so many outbound packets from the Windows desktop, *192.168.1.10* (which again, isn't on the Linksys SSID, so I might not have expected the Linksys to see these).

**How is it possible `iptables` is missing the Xbox packets that allowed the fast-paced online game to function?**

Comment: One clue to why no "destination" rules were getting matched... the "destination" rules seem to only get matches when placed on the POSTROUTING chain (which is the inverse of only the "source" getting matches in the PREROUTING chain above).  Makes sense for hosts on Linksys/TheOtherNetwork (where iptables is running), since incoming packets might only have a local address destination *after* getting routed.  Not sure how that makes sense for hosts on Netgear/TheNewNetwork since by the time the Linksys sees those packets they should already be addressed to the local endpoint by the Netgear.

Comment: See related (also unanswered):  https://superuser.com/q/1282651/981809